# Given a plain text and a possible cipher text, determine whether the cipher text can be formed from the plain text using the mentioned scheme

Tags: python, cryptography, cypher

The alphabets are enumerated as A = 0, B = 1, C = 2, ... , Z = 25. Consider an encryption scheme where a character with value Ci in the plaintext is replaced by another character with value Cj using the formula Cj = (Ci + 5) % 26. After replacement, the resulting string is shuffled (permuted) at random to obtain the cipher text.

Given a plain text and a possible cipher text, your task is to determine whether the cipher text can be formed from the plain text using the above mentioned scheme.

(Assume that all the strings are in uppercase)

Input Format:

The first line of the input contains a string indicating the plain text.

The second line of the input a string indicating a possible cipher text

Output Format:

Display Yes or No (no newline after the output)

Example:

Input:

PYTHON
TDMSUY

Output:

Yes

Input:

JOCPNPTEL
JQYVSUTHO

Output:

No

**Please answer in Python**

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648). Provide a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [IPYNB Formatted Code Here](https://roboticswithpython.com/week-12-iitropar-joy-of-computing-with-python-programming-nptel/)

```
s = input()
p = input()
#s = s[::-1]
t = ''
for c in s:
  t+=chr((ord(c)+5-ord('A'))%26 + ord('A'))
  

def removeSpaces(string): 
    string = string.replace(' ','') 
    string = string.replace(',','')
    return string.lower()
def check(t, p):
     
    # the sorted strings are checked 
    if(sorted(t)== sorted(p)):
        print("Yes",end='') 
    else:
        print("No",end='')         
         
check(t, p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys this is what i came up with

```
`x=input()
y=input()
a='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
t=''
for i in x:
  c=a.index(i)
  cj=(c+5)%26
  t=t+a[cj]
if(sorted(y)==sorted(t)):
  print("Yes",end='')
else:
  print("No",end='')`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a=input()
d={}
for i in a:
  d[chr(((ord(i)-60)%26)+65)]=d.get(chr(((ord(i)-60)%26)+65),0)+1
b=input()
for i in b:
  if d.get(i,0)<=0:
    print("No",end="")
    break
  d[i]-=1
else:
  print("Yes",end="")
```

Comment: can you format the code properly and add some explanation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].